# Implement cd command in c

Tags: c, shell, cd

How can we implement the cd command in c that support `~, .., -`
I write the following code:

```
void exec_cd(char* command) {
    if (chdir(command) != 0) {
        perror("chdir failed");
    }
    if (!strcmp(command, "~")) {
        chdir(getenv("HOME"));
    }
    if (!strcmp(command, "/")) {
        // do stuff
    }
    if (!strcmp(command, "-")) {
        // do stuff
    }
    if (!strcmp(directory, "..")) {
        chdir("..");
    }
}
```

How can we implement `~ and -` and the `..` command is correct?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but please note that `chdir` returns 0 on success. Please read the `man` of the function.

Comment: @Xavi : Your are accessing a variable `directory`, which does not seem to be defined. Also, doing a special case for `..` is unnecessary. The `chdir` function is able to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chdir` will change the current directory of your program, probably a command shell you are trying to implement.

Absolute and relative paths such as `/`, `..`, `subdir` pose no problem and can be passed directly to the `chdir` system call.

`-` is a special argument for the `cd` command: `cd -` means to go back to the previous current directory. To implement this functionality, you need to keep track of the last directory `cd` changed to. Use the `getcwd()` function for that before calling `chdir` and if successful, keep this previous directory in a global array.

`~` is another special thing: it should be expanded to the home directory (the value of the `HOME` environment variable) before dispatching to the command handler, so one can type `cd ~`, or just `cd` to change to the home directory but `cd "~"` to change to a directory named `"~"`. `~` should expand to `$(HOME)`, either as a stand alone string or as the initial portion of a path: `~/bin`. Note that `~name` should expand to the home directory of the user `name`.

Here is a partial and simplistic version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char lastdir[MAX_PATH];  // initialized to zero

int exec_cd(char *arg) {
    char curdir[MAX_PATH];
    char path[MAX_PATH];

    if (getcwd(curdir, sizeof curdir)) {
        /* current directory might be unreachable: not an error */
        *curdir = '\0';
    }
    if (arg == NULL) {
        arg = getenv("HOME");
    }
    if (!strcmp(arg, "-")) {
        if (*lastdir == '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "no previous directory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        arg = lastdir;
    } else {
        /* this should be done on all words during the parse phase */
        if (*arg == '~') {
            if (arg[1] == '/' || arg[1] == '\0') {
                snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s%s", getenv("HOME"), arg + 1);
                arg = path;
            } else {
                /* ~name should expand to the home directory of user with login `name` 
                   this can be implemented with getpwent() */
                fprintf(stderr, "syntax not supported: %s\n", arg);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (chdir(arg)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "chdir: %s: %s\n", strerror(errno), path);
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(lastdir, curdir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you get `*lastdir`

Comment: `lastdir` is a global `char` array. `*lastdir` is the same as `lastdir[0]`, the first byte of the array. If this byte is null, the previous current directory is unknown, either because the shell never changed directories or because it changed from an invalid directory, which is possible if the current directory was removed, as would happen after: `mkdir foo; cd foo; rmdir ../foo`.

Comment: Yes but you check whether `*lastdir == '\0'` when you didn't put inside nothing.

Comment: @Xavi: uninitialized global data is initialized to zero at program start time. `lastdir` will have all its bytes set to '\0', so it is an empty string.